# why doesn't catch block share the scope of the try block?

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, try-catch

Surprisingly, I can't find an answer to that by googling and searching SO (there are lots of similar questions on SO but related to other languages).

I suspect that the answer is `no`. If so, there is an obvious inconvenience, e.g.

```
try
{
  std::string fname = constructFileName(); // can throw MyException
  ofstream f;
  f.exceptions(ofstream::failbit | ofstream::badbit);
  f.open(fname.c_str());
  // ...
}
catch (ofstream::failure &e)
{
  cout << "opening file " << fname << " failed\n"; // fname is not in the scope
}
catch (MyException &e)
{
  cout << "constructing file name failed\n";
}
```

If my assumption is correct, how do you deal with this? By moving the `std::string fname;` out of `try`, I guess?

I understand that a scope is defined by a `{}` block, but this seems as a reasonable case for, hmm, exception. Is the reason for that that objects can be not fully constructed if an exception is thrown?

Comment: Right on the spot. If in `try { A a; B b; }` the constructor for `A` throws, neither `a` nor `b` can reasonably be in scope.

Comment: Aside from anything else, the compiler likely doesn't know whether `constructFileName()` can throw `ofstream::failure`. If `fname` is still in scope in the first `catch` block, think about when it's going to be destructed - after the catch executes, but conditionally on where the throw came from. Yuck. You could try to tell the compiler what each function throws, but I don't much fancy objects having a lifetime and scope that depends on the exception-specification of `constructFileName()`. Much cleaner to destroy everything created before the throw point, then deal with catch clauses.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Does `catch` block share the scope of the `try` block?

No.

> How do you deal with this?  By moving the `std::string fname;` out of `try`, I guess?

Yes.

> I understand that a scope is defined by a `{}` block, but this seems as a reasonable case for, hmm, exception. Is the reason for that that objects can be not fully constructed if an exception is thrown?

The last thing C++ needs is more complex rules and exceptions to rules. :-)

Answer (score 12):

There's an obvious reason: you cannot trust the state of the objects that were created inside the try block.  The code there got interrupted by the exception, their constructors might not even have run yet.

Comment: I don't think this is obvious. For instance in python which also has constructors, a try block does not define a new scope.

Comment: @Étienne That is not an appropriate comparison. In Python, what variable you're referencing is determined dynamically at runtime. So, if a variable isn't constructed, that name doesn't even exist. In C++, that's not the case.

Answer (score 4):

While James' post correctly answers your questions, it doesn't supply the usual workaround: `swap`. Assuming `constructFileName()` returns `std::string` and not `char const*`, the following is idiomatic:

```
std::string fname;
try
{
    constructFileName().swap(fname); // can throw MyException
    std::ofstream f;
    f.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::badbit);
    f.open(fname.c_str());
    // ...
}
catch (std::ios_base::failure &e)
{
    std::cout << "opening file " << fname << " failed\n";
}
catch (MyException &e)
{
    std::cout << "constructing file name failed\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks. Why `swap` is better here than assignment? If an exception is thrown during assignment, does this leave the `fname` in an undefined state?

Comment: @davka : With a pre-C++0x compiler, `operator=` would cause there to be two copies of the data during assignment, which is highly and completely unnecessarily inefficient, whereas with `swap` there will be at most one copy of the data. With a C++0x compiler it won't matter either way in this case, since the result of `constructFileName` would be an rvalue and consequently moved into `fname` (also ensuring there will be at most one copy of the data). In short: `swap` is much more efficient on all but cutting-edge compilers.

Answer (score 1):

They are outside of the scope. This is because if you declare an object and try to initialise it, and the way you initialise it throws an exception, it will be caught.